# Dropdown post live search ,add onclick redirect to post (php page)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

**Hi,**
*i am coding a homepage to learn php and javascript. I decided to use a livesearch using jQuery and php.
It is working well ,but i wonder how i can integrate to the found titles an onclick function that will redirect to the viewpost.php so it opens the clicked title and opens the post.*

**My HTML search part on index page:**

```
<!-- Search Widget -->
<div class="card my-4">
<div class="card bg-success">
  <h5 class="card-header">Search</h5>
  <div class="card-body">
        <div class="search-box">
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search country..." />
<div class="result"></div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery part for livesearch that redirect to php page(backend-search.php)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.search-box input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function(){
        /* Get input value on change */
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
        if(inputVal.length){
            $.get("backend-search.php", {term: inputVal}).done(function(data){
                // Display the returned data in browser
                resultDropdown.html(data);
                
            });
        } else{
            resultDropdown.empty();
        }
    });
    
    // Set search input value on click of result item
    $(document).on("click", ".result p", function(){
        $(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
        $(this).parent(".result").empty();
    });
});
</script>
```

**PHP backend-search.php**

```
<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
require_once "pdoconfig.php";
 
// Attempt search query execution
try{
    if(isset($_REQUEST["term"])){
        // create prepared statement
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title LIKE :term";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $term = $_REQUEST["term"] . '%';
        // bind parameters to statement
        $stmt->bindParam(":term", $term);
        // execute the prepared statement
        $stmt->execute();
        if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
            while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
                echo "<p>" . $row["title"] . "</p>";                
            }
        } else{
            echo "<p>No matches found</p>";
        }
    }  
} catch(PDOException $e){
    die("ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . $e->getMessage());
}
 
// Close statement
unset($stmt);
 
// Close connection
unset($db);
?>
```

**That is my table structure called articles:**

```
id  title content categorie_id pubdate views short_details
```

**And finally my viewpost.php**

```
<?php
 $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT id, title, text, pubdate FROM articles WHERE id = :id');
 $stmt->execute(array(':id' => $_GET['id']));
 $row = $stmt->fetch();
//if post does not exists redirect user.
if($row['id'] == ''){
    header('Location: ./');
    exit;
}
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<div class='card mb-4'>" . "<div class='card-body'>";
            echo "<h2 class='card-title'>";     
            echo $row['title'] . "</h2>";
            echo "<div class='card-footer text-muted'>";
            echo $row['pubdate'];
            echo "</h2>";
            echo "<p class='card-text'>";
            echo $row['text'];
            echo "</p>";
            echo '</div>';
        ?>
```

*Do i need to get the articles id with the jQuery and somehow post it onclick to viewpost.php ?
I do appreciate all help ..*

[image]

Comment: Hi you can use `a` tag i.e :`<p><a href="viewpost.php?id=".$row['id'].">".$row['title'] ."</a> </p> ";` so when user will click on any title it will get redirect to `viewpost` page with required `id` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Need To Change This PHP **"backend-search.php"** File :

This Code To

```
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
{
   while($row = $stmt->fetch())
   {
      echo "<p>" . $row["title"] . "</p>";                
   }
} 
else
{
    echo "<p>No matches found</p>";
}
```

This Code

```
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
{
   while($row = $stmt->fetch())
   {
      echo "<p><a href=\"viewpost.php?id=".$row["id"]."\">". $row["title"] . "</a></p>";                
   }
} 
else
{
    echo "<p>No matches found</p>";
}
```

Comment: Working just perfect!